# can't use get_query_var when including template in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, parameters, action

I am using this function (in Wordpress's functions.php file) to redirect a specific url to a specific php script file:

```
add_action('init', function() {
$url_path = trim(parse_url(add_query_arg(array()), PHP_URL_PATH), '/');
if ( $url_path === 'manoa' ) {
$load = locate_template('inc/manoa.php', true);
if ($load) {exit();}
}});
```

(i know i can use rewrite rules, but i rather use that for a few reasons).

it works great. except i can't use get_query_var on that page. any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a different add_action rather than init.
Try to use `add_action('wp')` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but still can't use get_query_var.

Comment: wp does it! `add_action('wp')`. can you update the answer? thanks!

Comment: @mondi Changed my answer!

Comment: Great! Thank you!